Resources for computational approaches to stochastic processes
Broad, education/resource question. I’d like to know more about stochastic processes and in particular discrete processes.
For example the binomial pricing model converges on geometric Brownian motion when the step size is arbitrarily small and the number of steps is arbitrarily large.
Finance is not central to my interest area but this example illustrates my interest in discrete approximations of continuous processes. The poisson process for event arrival times, querying theory, etc is also of interest to me.
I’d prioritize the ability to address a variety of use cases computationally over being able to prove or derive an analytic solution for any one such use case.
My domain is in logistics and operations research. So discrete events are often of greater importance than continuous analogs.
I frequently use Python, but could understand other languages.
Are any books or courses recommended?
